# how to access all setting Show Acquisition Wizard

Tags: c#, image, wia, image-scanner

I have feeder scanner so I use this code

```
 device=w.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,true,false);
    commondialog.ShowAcquisitionWizard(device);
```

and successfully scanned all images in scanner but I want to access the path of these images stored by wizard to take these images and stored in database how can I get the path from `c#` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used scan dll it is a fantastic dll

[scan sdk](http://bytescoutscansdk.codeplex.com/)